# Refer variable in SQL query in java MVC

Tags: java, sql, model-view-controller

I'm working on a java mvc project i was suppose to retrieve a emotion happy based on the query here i get  the word happy dynamically in a variable called last. Now when i use query it gives this error.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

my code
**myController.java**

```
session.setAttribute("ls",ud.getLast());

ud.setLast(last);

System.out.println("notequallllll"+last);
String last1=(String) session.getAttribute("ls");
System.out.println("outtttt"+last1);

ud.setLast(last1);

List<UserData> uli=ms.viewEmotion(ud);

UserData u=uli.get(0);

mod.addAttribute("pc", u.getFile());
```

**Mydao.java**

```
 public List<UserData> viewEmotion(UserData ud)
{
    //ud.getLast();
    String last=ud.getLast();
    System.out.println("daooooo"+last);
    BeanPropertySqlParameterSource params=new  
    BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(ud);
    return jdbc.query(**"select * from tblemotion where topic='negative' and emotion='"+last+"'"**,params,new RowMapper<UserData>() {

        @Override
        public UserData mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
                throws SQLException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            UserData u=new UserData();
            u.setId(rs.getString("eid"));
            System.out.println(rs.getString("eid"));
            u.setFile(rs.getString("image"));
            return u;
        }
    });
}
```